# Why my email confirmation token is invalid?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to get clean emailconfirmation on Microsoft Identity 2.0. I'm generating email link for confirmation and it's not working. 
I found, that encoded token on callbackrul is changing to lowercase and I believe that there is a problem. But I don't know how to solve it.....

When code variable gets value it looks like:
CfDJ8C5jg3XNISFEoFA015AdmTmmbOmQG/cxNBfdOALg4WM+iU6uf8WeJ13buFIzbdlP3tK3kWU1Q6BwGh/DY7dAYqbj+zz7jXGOK1Y79mtDT2jiEKV4NdaLbfaruzOvoKSVhvg4EFVYPAQRrjcAnOkfCxlff6hMVhIBWHkg8rqv7GBnqXvJ+UbCErqlobIxI69YreNWVTM1Z4lkAYQM2xmwRA//0T53KNPTWIX52oDc52eFLJAlsWhXI9uHwgfwTt0X9g==

After callback it's changed to:
cfdj8c5jg3xnisfeofa015admtmmbomqg%2Fcxnbfdoalg4wm%2Biu6uf8wej13bufizbdlp3tk3kwu1q6bwgh%2Fdy7dayqbj%2Bzz7jxgok1y79mtdt2jiekv4ndalbfaruzovoksvhvg4efvypaqrrjcanokfcxlff6hmvhibwhkg8rqv7gbnqxvj%2Bubcerqlobixi69yrenwvtm1z4lkayqm2xmwra%2F%2F0t53knptwix52odc52efljalswhxi9uhwgfwtt0x9g%3D%3D

On confirmation action I'm getting decoded token as:
cfdj8c5jg3xnisfeofa015admtmmbomqg/cxnbfdoalg4wm+iu6uf8wej13bufizbdlp3tk3kwu1q6bwgh/dy7dayqbj+zz7jxgok1y79mtdt2jiekv4ndalbfaruzovoksvhvg4efvypaqrrjcanokfcxlff6hmvhibwhkg8rqv7gbnqxvj+ubcerqlobixi69yrenwvtm1z4lkayqm2xmwra//0t53knptwix52odc52efljalswhxi9uhwgfwtt0x9g==

Part of register.cshtml.cs

```
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                  "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                  pageHandler: null,
                  values: new { userId = user.Id, code = codeenc },
                  protocol: Request.Scheme
                  );
await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");
```

confirmemail.cshtml.cs

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    if (user == null)
       {
          return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
       }
var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
```

So where I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but did you try this one?
 `code = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);`

Comment: Yes, didn't help

Comment: On debug when I'm on callbackurl i see mixed letters, but on next step (await on emailsender) callbackurl shows token in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in my startup.cs file,

```
options.LowercaseQueryStrings = true;
```

After comment token is working ok.